# Why doesn't new require a cast to the pointer even though malloc requires it?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

The definition of new in the <new> header is:

```
 void* operator new(size_t);
```

And the definition of malloc is as stated:

```
 void* malloc(size_t);
```

Now, as C++ is a strongly typed language, it requires a cast from the programmer to convert a void* pointer to the type the programmer requires... In malloc, we have to perform a cast, but not in new, though both return a void* pointer. Why?

Comment: check this out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6555/To-new-is-C-To-malloc-is-C-To-mix-them-is-sin

Comment: also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new

Comment: Also check out : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1885849/1155650

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because when you're using `new`, you (normally) use a "new expression", which allocates and initializes an object. You're then assigning the address of that object to a pointer to an object of the same (or parent) type, which doesn't require a cast. A normal new expression (i.e., not a placement new) will invoke `operator new` internally but the result of the new expression is *not* just the result from `operator new`.

If you invoke `operator new` directly, then you need to cast its result to assign the return value to a non-void pointer, just like you have to do with the return from `malloc`.

Comment: The accepted [and brilliant :-)] answer to the question to which @Rohit linked goes into more detail about that.

Answer (score 5):

Because you have the wrong impression how to use `malloc`. It doesn't receive the type as an argument but only the size of the type.

C and C++ are different languages. In C you don't need to cast the `void*` of `malloc` to the target pointer type. In C++ the `new` operator is deeply build into the language such that it always returns a value corresponding to the type you gave in the argument.

The rule is quite simple use `new` for C++ and `malloc` for C, don't mix them.

Comment: How does new receives the type as the argument??

Comment: @bhuwansahni, `new` is an operator not a function. In the place that you use it you always give it the type of the object that is to be allocated and constructed. It is up to the compiler to make the link. In C for a call to `malloc` you only give the size.

Comment: @bhuwansahni, because it is not necessary. To write a generic `operator new` the only property of the target type you need is the size. The type specific stuff is ensure by compiler by calling the appropriate constructor for the type.

Comment: @bhuwansahni: you are confusing the new operator and operator new. They are two different things. The new operator is a syntax for allocating and constructing objects. Operator new is a special declaration syntax for declaring and writing functions which implement memory allocation, connected to the new operator. new int(3) knows the size of int in the same way that sizeof(int) does: they are operators that operate with types. The new operator calculates the size and passes it to the appropriate operator new function.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `operator new` call is only a single step generated in the entire chain when you invoke `new`.

When you do `s=new my_type(args);`, the compiler will expand that to:

```
s = (my_type*)my_type.operator new(sizeof(my_type));
s.my_type(args); //Constructor call
```