# Difference between "new" operator and "new" function

Tags: c++, operators

**Interview question:** what's the difference between "new" operator and "new" function?

I answered there is no difference, that they run the same code, but interviewer kept needling me like that was the wrong answer.

*Is it* the wrong answer? Or was the interviewer just playing games with me?

If it's the wrong answer, what's the right answer?

I continued that the "new" operator could be overloaded if you needed a custom allocation, but then he wanted to know *how* to overload it. Of course I didn't have that answer, having never had the need, but I told him I could look it up in 10 minutes (which is *never* the right answer in an interview).

So anyhow, having done some research on "new" operator vs. "new" function and not seeing any really satisfying answers, I thought I'd ask the specific question.

Comment: What's the new function? I've never heard of such a function in standard C++ (note that I'm not a C++ guy).

Comment: Is the new *function* that you refer to the same thing as *operator* new? That's generally what it's called, and it should help you to Google for answers.

Comment: Probably the question was the difference between new operator and operator new. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885849/difference-between-new-operator-and-operator-new .

Comment: @Heisenbug Agree. That Q contain a super clear definition of this question.

Answer (score 17):

The `new` operator and `operator new` are not the same thing.

The `new` operator calls an `operator new` function to allocate memory, and then, depending on the type allocated and the syntax used, initializes or calls a constructor on the allocated memory. In other words, `operator new` forms only a part of the operation of the `new` operator.

`operator new` is the function called to allocate memory by the `new` operator. There's a default implementation of `operator new` which can be *replaced*, which is not the same thing as overloading. `operator new` can also be implemented for [a particular type](http://ideone.com/UdTIj) to handle allocations only of objects of that type, or `operator new` can be overloaded and the overload can be selected by using the placement new form of the `new` operator.

The default implementations of `operator new` can be replaced by defining functions with the following signatures:

```
void *operator new(std::size_t size);
void *operator new(std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&);
void *operator new[](std::size_t size);
void *operator new[](std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&);
```

When you provide a replacement or overload for `operator new` you should provide corresponding `operator delete` functions:

```
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete(void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept;
void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete[](void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept;
```

To provide an overload of `operator new` for use with the placement form of the `new` operator you can add additional arguments (the nothrow versions of `operator new` and `operator delete` do this).

```
struct my_type {};

void *operator new(std::size_t size, const my_type&);
void operator delete(void *ptr, const my_type&);

new (my_type()) int(10); // allocate an int using the operator new that takes a my_type object
```

There is no 'placement delete' form of the `delete` operator. The overload of `operator delete` is provided because if an error occurs during the initialization/construction of the memory (e.g., the constructor called by the `new` operator after `operator new` has been called) the corresponding `operator delete` is called if it exists before re-throwing the exception. Otherwise `operator delete` is not called and [the memory leaks](http://ideone.com/S4TCW) when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Basically:-
Function: "operator new"

```
 class Example 
{ public:
         void* operator new( size_t );
 }
```

"new operator":

```
Example* eg = new Example();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I continued that the "new" operator could be overloaded if you needed
>   a custom allocation

You are almost right.
`new` is a keyword for an operator, which is used for memory allocation.

*Why is this an operator ?*
On need basis, it can be overloaded as a function **both** at global scope or class scope (but NOT `namespace` scope!). This wouldn't have been possible if it was a function.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in how they function. The initial allocation part is, per standard I believe, the same. That is, using syntax new vs operator new() explicitly is very much the same. The difference, is using new initializes or constructs the new object. There is also 3 different versions of ::operator new() and there is various syntaxes to utilize them as well (i.e., placement new).

Answer (score 0):

There is no new function. My guess is that they wanted you to say that one of these allocated the memory (the standard uses *allocator function*, *function new operator* and *new operator* for it) and that the other used the first to allocate memory, then called the constructor (the standard uses *new expression*) and the deallocator function (aka *function delete operator* or *delete operator*) to free the memory if the constructor exited with an exception.