# Assigning operator new() to a function pointer?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, new-operator

I'm trying to define a class which can be passed an "object allocator" function and takes the template object's operator new() as the default argument.  I have the following code:

```
template<class _Obj>
class Foo
{
private:
    typedef _Obj (_Obj::*fp_alloc_type)();

public:
    Foo(fp_alloc_type t=_Obj::operator new ());

...
};
```

This gives a comiler error C2039: *'new' : is not a member of 'SomeObj'*

Does the compiler not generate a default implementation of 'new' for objects which do not define their own?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. The compiler does not generate `operator new` for your class. Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: Then why am I able to call new _Obj()?  Is that not _Obj::operator new()?

Comment: @jwalk, nope. It's global new. `::operator new()`

Comment: Does c++ not already have an allocator class? `template < class T > class allocator`

Comment: This previous thread may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885849/difference-between-new-operator-and-operator-new

Comment: @StoryTeller Or not.  The compiler follows very specific rules of name lookup here, which are a bit different than those of any other function (since they ignore any namespaces which contain the class).  But it's possible to hide the global `operator new`.  Of course, if the programmer writes `::new Foo`, then it will use `::operator new()`, regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever else it may be, the `operator new` function is *not*
a non-static member function of any class.  Even if you declare
and define a class specific operator new, it is considered
a static member function; if it takes a single, `size_t`
argument, then a pointer to it would be `void* (*ptrToNew)(
size_t )`.  (If it is a placement new, of course, there will be
more arguments.)

When you do `new Foo`, the compiler does a name lookup on
`operator new` first in the scope of `Foo` (if `Foo` is a class
type), then in the global namespace.  (Interestingly enough, the
compiler will *not* look in the namespace in which `Foo` is
declared.  Nor does ADL ever apply.  An `operator new` function
in a namespace other than the global namespace will never be
found.)  Unless you've declared an `operator new` in the class,
the global `operator new` function will be used.

Comment: Just as a follow-up, I'm guessing then that there's no standard way to grab a pointer to the object's implementation of the new operator?

Comment: @jwalk An object doesn't have an implementation of the `operator new` function.  If there is a class specific `operator new`, `void* (*ptrNew)( size_t ) = &Foo::operator new` should work.  If you don't know whether there is a class specific `operator new`, you'll need some sort of meta programming to find out.  But why do you want it?

Comment: I was interested to write an implementation of an object pool pattern that takes an optional arg in the constructor for allocation method of the objects in the pool.