# Can I bind to new char[]?

Tags: c++, bind

I can create a function object to create a 100 byte block on the heap using malloc:

```
auto fn = std::bind(malloc, 100);
```

But what is the equivalent using `new char[]`? I realize I can `bind` to a function or lambda that returns `new char[100]` but I'd like to understand the syntax for binding to `new char[]` directly.

Is it even possible, or is `new char[]` an operator rather than a function and therefore cannot be bound?

Thanks, Craig

Comment: Yes, at least as you're using it, `new` is an operator. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1885897/179910 for more details.

Comment: auto x = std::bind(operator new[], 100); ...but no

Comment: `auto fn = [](){return new char[];};` Seems to work

Comment: @rcapote that's a lambda! ;)

Comment: `new char[]` is a call to an operator, which calls _several_ functions.  `void* ::operator new(size_t)` and then "the default constructor" for each `char` object. (In truth, that's skipped in this case for obvious reasons).  It also stores the number of elements in some unspecified location.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
auto fn = bind<void*>(operator new[], sizeof(char)*100);

auto field = (char*)fn();
```

Comment: (1) [That doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=38361e5d056b11f72c6f4dfeef060c12-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) (2), `new char[]` is more than just a call to `operator new[]`, even for `char` types.

Comment: @MooingDuck You must include the header file `iostream` because there is the `operator new[]` declared.

Comment: @MooingDuck I just debugged the following instruction: `int *test = new int[20];` and it calls exactly the same `operator new[]` method defined in `newaop.cpp`.
It's just an evaluation of the type that you use, multiplied by the number in the square bracket.
  
`void *__CRTDECL operator new[](size_t count) 
 { 
 return (operator new(count));
 }`
In my instance the variable `count` was 80 => 20 * int = 20 * 4 Byte

Comment: half right.  I checked, `::operator new` is defined in the `<new>` header, not `<memory>` like I thought.  However, `operator new[]` isn't bindable like that because it's overloaded.  The best I could do was [this](http://ideone.com/tNmwQi)

Comment: I never claimed that `new int[20]` didn't call `void* ::operator new[](size_t)`,  what I said that that function is only the _first of many things_ that the `new` operator does.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes but the `new` operator works completely independent on which type you are using. It always calls the same functions because the `new` operator works internally with the type `void`.
It's strange why this code doesn't run with your compiler. I use Visual Studio 2012 and it works just like I have expected.

Comment: http://ideone.com/vJq3qO In this case, I would guess Visual Studio is "cheating" the official rules to guess what you want and compile it.  They also do this with templates a lot.  To be fair, GCC cheats with runtime sized automatic arrays, so it's not just one compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want space, you're correct that can simply bind `::operator new`, but *in the general case*, `new T[]` does more.  Unfortunately, `::operator new` is overloaded, so the compiler doesn't know which one you want, so you have to "cast" it to get the right overload. [tom1991t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372782/tom1991te) says MSVC compiles it without the cast, but I don't think the compiler is supposed to do that.

```
#include <functional>
#include <new>

int main() {
    typedef void*(*newptr_type)(std::size_t);  
    typedef void(*delptr_type)(void*);        
    auto al = std::bind<void*>(newptr_type(::operator new), sizeof(char)*100);   
    auto dl = delptr_type(::operator delete);   

    auto field = (char*)al();
    dl(field); //or just "delete[] field;"
}
```

Note that this is *not* the same as `new T[]` in the general case, since this doesn't construct nor would the inverse `::operator delete` call any destructors, but for `char` we don't care.

Some compilers refuse to inline function pointers under any conditions, so a functionoid would be better, including a lambda (As suggested by [rcapote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196089/rcapote)).  This solution could handle constructors and destructors, and should run faster due to inlining.

```
auto al = [](){return new char[100];};
auto dl = [](char* p){delete[] p;};

auto field = (char*)al();
dl(field); //or just "delete[] field;"
```

[Proof of compilation](http://ideone.com/luNybc)