# Source code showing new() invoking object's constructor at malloc-returned address

Tags: c++, gcc, new-operator

I have managed to find the GCC source code showing the new() operator making a call to malloc() in new_op.cc:

```
_GLIBCXX_WEAK_DEFINITION void *
operator new (std::size_t sz) _GLIBCXX_THROW (std::bad_alloc)
{
  void *p;

  /* malloc (0) is unpredictable; avoid it.  */
  if (sz == 0)
    sz = 1;
  p = (void *) malloc (sz);
  while (p == 0)
    {
      new_handler handler = __new_handler;
      if (! handler)
    _GLIBCXX_THROW_OR_ABORT(bad_alloc());
      handler ();
      p = (void *) malloc (sz);
    }

  return p;
}
```

However, I am trying to find the code where the object constructor is invoked at the memory address returned from above (I presume placement new would be used??).

Where can I find this in GCC?

Comment: You can change only the allocation - not the construction after 'new' returns

Comment: The constructor call is inserted at the site of the new-expression by the compiler. Simple example: http://goo.gl/T4uGmr.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! So where is the code which tells the constructor to put its allocation at the address returned from new operator?

Comment: @user3811839 Bit hard to explain the assembly in a comment. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor call is inserted at the site of the new-expression by the compiler. You can look at the disassembly of a simple program:

```
struct A { A() noexcept; ~A() = default; } ;
int main(){
    new A;
}
```

[produces](http://goo.gl/T4uGmr) for the `new A;` expression (with g++ 4.9 at `-O0` on Linux 64-bit):

```
movl    $1, %edi                         ; copy the size of A into edi (the lower 32 bits of `rdi`)
call    operator new(unsigned long)      ; call the operator new function to allocate memory
movq    %rax, %rdi                       ; copy the return value (in rax) to rdi
call    A::A()                           ; call the constructor
```

x64 calling convention on Linux for a function taking a single integer or pointer parameter is that the parameter is passed in the `rdi` register and the return value is placed in `rax`. (While `A::A()` seems to take no parameter, like all non-static class member functions, it has a hidden `this` parameter.) So in this case, the compiler generates code to copy the pointer returned by `operator new()` in `rax` to `rdi`, to be passed to `A`'s constructor as the hidden `this` parameter, and then calls the constructor.

Note that this code is vastly simplified by declaring `A::A()` as `noexcept`, so the compiler can assume that the constructor call will never throw an exception.

As to placement new, it's implemented in the same way - except that it calls the placement `operator new(size_t, void *)` - whose implementation simply returns the pointer passed. The compiler then generates code that calls the constructor, passing the return value of the placement `operator new()` as the `this` parameter.

Comment: Ah I did think the pointer was an implicit "this" pointer in to the constructor! :)

Answer (score 2):

`operator new` is just a plain old function, it only allocates bulk memory, it does not invoke constructors etc. It is the job of `new` keyword (sometimes called `new operator`, super confusing) to do the latter.

See [Difference between 'new operator' and 'operator new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885849/3093378)
for a similar question.

So when you call

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
```

you actually first call `operator new(sizeof(Foo))`, that returns a pointer to the memory area that it allocates, then `new` is constructing the object in the memory returned by the first call by invoking the appropriate constructor/in-class initialization.

Comment: Thanks. Ok so I guess my question is, can I see the code for "new keyword"?

Comment: Have no idea how/where it is internally implemented, but it is a feature of the language itself. It should probably be implemented somewhere though... Nowadays even the `C++` compiler is written in `C++`, so you should probably dig quite deep.