# What's the difference between call constructor from new overload and directly?

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, constructor-overloading

Considering below code, when I call `new(name, 10) Foo()` I expect the following to happen, in that order:

1. `void* operator new(std::size_t size, QString name, int id)` overload to be called
2. `Foo(QString name, int id)` constructor called from above overload
   at this time, enough memory is allocated to my class so I can safely do and set:

   name(name), id(id)
3. Call `Foo()` empty constructor and do nothing. Only here because must be implemented.

But I missing something. The member name value is empty. Would someone explain what and how to fix?

The code:

Note: QString is Qt's [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) type

```
class Foo
{
public:
    QString name;
    int id;

    // The idea is return an already existing instance of a class with same values that
    // we are going to construct here.
    void* operator new(std::size_t size, QString name, int id)
    {
        Foo *f = getExistingInstance(name, id);

        if(f != NULL)
            return f;

        /* call to constructor Foo(QString, int) is an alias for:
         *      Foo* *p = static_cast<Foo*>(operator new(size));
         *      p->name = name;
         *      p->id = id;
         *      return p;
         * I don't think it's wrong on ambiguos in the below call to constructor, since it does use
         * operator new(std::size_t size) and Foo(QString name, int id) "methods"
         */
        return new Foo(name, id);
    }

    void* operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        void *ptr = malloc(size);
        assert(ptr);
        return ptr;
    }

    Foo(QString name, int id)
        : name(name),
          id(id)
    {

    }

    Foo()
    {

    }

    ~Foo()
    {

    }

    QString toString()
    {
        return QString("name = %1, id = %2")
                .arg(name)
                .arg(id);
    }

    static Foo* getExistingInstance(QString name, int id)
    {
        /* not implemented yet */
        return NULL;
    }
};
```

How I call this:

```
 QString name = "BILL";
 Foo *f = new(name, 10) Foo();
 qDebug() << f->toString(); //output "name = , id = 10"
 delete f;
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: extra parameters in new operator should be used to select memory management strategy. This is useful when implementing custom container which will menage own memory. This values shouldn't be used to initialize object.

Comment: @MarekR: The parameters passed to new operator are exactly the same that I would pass the constructor to create the object so I just pass it once

Answer (score 0):

`Foo *f = new (name, 10) Foo;`
allocates memory using the overloaded `ǹew` operator and after that initializes the memory with a default constructed `Foo` (which only overwrites `name` but not `id` since `id` is not initialized in the defualt constructor).

You can see that by placing e.g. `qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;` in Foo's constructors.

See [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106449/why-overloaded-new-operator-is-calling-constructor-even-i-am-using-malloc-inside) for a similar question.

Comment: Which default constructor are you talking about the C++-generated-one or the mine? I didn't understand how the `name` value gets overrried and `id` doesn't. Both are set at constructor `Foo(QString, int)`

Comment: `Foo *f = new (name, 10) Foo;` calls your constructor `Foo()`; `Foo *f = new (name, 10) Foo(name, 10);` would call the `Foo(QString, int)` constructor.

Comment: I was trying to initialize the membersfrom `void* operator new(std::size_t size, QString name, int id)` overload whch calls `Foo(QString, int)` constructor. In the call to `Foo()` the value is supposed to be already set so it does nothing.