# Confusion about calling operator new function directly

Tags: c++, new-operator

I know that we normally don't call `operator new` & `operator delete` function directly. Because If I do so constructor & destructor won't be called & it likely ends up with memory leak. But for primitive types this seems not problematic. Correct me If I am wrong.

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int* p=(int*)operator new (3);
    std::cout<<*p;
    operator delete(p);
}
```

Why it prints garbage value as output? What I have done wrong here? I am curious to know about how to correctly give value by calling operator new function directly. I want the output of program 3 as a output, but by not using new operator like **int* p=new int(3);**. What should I do?

Comment: _"Because If I do so constructor & destructor won't be called & it likely ends up with memory leak."_ Where did you hear this? Where should a memory leak come from?

Comment: You misunderstood it. That says that the destructor won't be invoked, which is problematic _if the destructor has work to do_. In this case you use `int`, which has no members which need clearing up. No memory leak.

Comment: Also, you said yourself that the constructor won't be called so I don't understand why you think `3` will function as a constructor argument here. Read those links yourself.

Comment: Um just set the value? `*p = 3`?

Comment: Create the integer normally? `int* ptr = new int(3)` or `int x = 3`? I don't understand what you're trying to do. You're saying "I really want to use this strange syntax that doesn't invoke the constructor. How do I use it to invoke the constructor?"

Comment: It's better to say there is no memory leak for `int` because `int` doesn't manage any dynamically-allocated resources. It's just a number.

Comment: No thanks; I must charge a fee for one-on-one mentoring/teaching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You only allocate *three bytes*
2. You don't initialize the memory you allocate.

Both of these will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The argument to the `operator new` ***function*** is the number of bytes to allocate, not what to initialize the allocated memory to.

The `new` operator, and the function `operator new` are two different things that behaves differently.

See [this old question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885849/440558) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main misunderstanding in your code is that you think that here:

```
int* p=(int*)operator new (3);
```

You are doing this:

```
int* p = new int(3);
```

It prints garbage value because your `int` to which `p` points has not been initialized.

What you actually do is you allocate 3 bytes of memory for storing and `int`. So int pointer `p` will now point to memory are with 3 bytes allocated (on most platforms you need 4 bytes to store an `int`).

See the [new C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) for more information (first overload is what you should check).