# Do I cast the result of new in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, new-operator, heap-memory

In the answers to the question [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) was covered that I do not need and should not cast the returned `void` pointer of `malloc()` in C.

But how is it about the `new` operator in C++?

---

Is there an explicit reason to *only* do:

```
int *p_rt = new int;
```

instead of

```
int *p_tr = (int*) new int;
```

Or can I do the cast?

Comment: Why would you cast? Also, the use of `new` is taught in every C++ tutorial, what does it say there? That said, two notes: There is a "new operator" and something called "operator new". The distinction is very advanced C++ though, don't bother with that now. Secondly, avoid using C-style casts, as in above code! They are dangerous and usually bad.

Comment: Why do you ask for a reason to use the shorter syntax? I kind of expected the opposite question.

Comment: I believe the whole point of `new` was to avoid the need for an explicit cast in a language that then didn't have templates. Casts defeat type safety. C++ has aimed to be a more type-safe C.

Comment: No there's no reason to cast. The result of `new any_type` is `any_type*`. Doing an explicit cast to `any_type*` is just useless.

Comment: `new int` returns an `int*`. Why would you cast an `int*` to an `int*` before assigning it to an `int*` variable?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was confused about it and thought `new` would return `void*` after I´ve read: `void* operator new (std::size_t size);` here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/

Comment: Ah but that's *different*! The `operator new` function is *called* by the `new` operator. They do different things though: The `new` operator (as in `new int`) will call `operator new` to allocate memory, then if the type is one that have a constructor it will be called, and then it results in a pointer to the allocated object with the correct type. You can call the `operator new` function yourself if you want, but then you need to cast the result to the correct type, and remember that like `malloc`, the function call will only allocate memory, not construct objects.

Comment: OP: do not answer in the question. You can answer your own question. I've [done it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59930767/5470596).

Comment: There are basically three kinds of `new` in C++. The `new` _expression_ (1), which you use, allocates memory by _operator_ `new` (2) and construct the object by _placement new_ (3).

Comment: not sure if it was already mentioned, another reason not to cast the result of `new` is not to use `new` in the first place ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new

Comment: @downvoters I don't undertand the downvotes. Can anyone please explain it?

Comment: @Maverobot Thanks for your support. Well, I made a mistake by myself in the distinction between `new` and `operator new`. All blame on me. But I think, too, that the downvotes wouldn´t be that necessary. If the question may be based on confusion, just explain how the things really are in a kind way and everything is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new T` returns `T*`, thus there is no need to cast it:

```
T* p = new T;
```

---

The return type of `malloc` on the other hand, is `void*`, so it must be cast to `T*` in C++:

```
T* p = static_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof(T));
```

---

Also note that as pointed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929999/do-i-cast-the-result-of-new-in-c/59930055#comment105982087_59930055), `new T` not only allocates the memory for the new object, but also constructs the object in that memory. `malloc` doesn't do it, so you must construct the object manually with [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: It should be noted that `new T` does *more* than just the plain allocation that `malloc` does. With `new T` the object is also constructed (the constructor is called).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an explicit reason to do:
>
> ```
> int *p_rt = new int;
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> int *p_rt = (*int) new int;
> ```

Yes, there are reasons to use the first. Reinterpret casts disable type diagnostics, and often result in bugs. You should avoid them if at all possible. Casting a pointer to the same type has no advantages.

P.S. Your attempted cast is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your information. My compiler, g++, passed it through without an error. Where is the  `int *p_tr = (int*) new int;` syntactically wrong exactly?

Comment: Well, now I´ve tested it secondly on a different online compiler and I get the warning: `warning: unused variable 'p_tr' [-Wunused-variable]`. Why is `p_tr` unused?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio The error is in the part `(*int)`. `Why is p_tr unused? ` Because you haven't used it for anything.

Comment: Ah, yes. It was only for testing purposes. Good, that I get warnings when I do not use any allocated object. - So the cast of `(*int)` is a syntax error? So, that would also be a reason to do not cast the return.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit made to the question transformed into an answer

Edit: My confusion was made because I´ve read `void* operator new (std::size_t size);` at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/ and thought `new` would return `void*`.

Thanks to the comments of @Someprogrammerdude and @UlrichEckhardt I´ve faced that the `new` operator and `operator new` are two different things and that `new` as opposed to `malloc()` explicitly returns a pointer of the respective type.

For everyone who encounters this question in the future, I would like to provide a link to the question where the difference between them two is described explicitly: [Difference between 'new operator' and 'operator new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885849/difference-between-new-operator-and-operator-new)

Answer (score 0):

unlike malloc() the new operator in c++ does already return a pointer of the allocated type. So there is no need to cast. In c the typechecking isnt as strict so you dont have to cast void* to the type you want. The data will automatically be interpretet as the type you have specified. If you are allocating in C++ with malloc on the other hand you should cast (else you might get compiler warnings).

Answer (score 0):

C allows the compiler to perform an implicit conversion from a `void*` pointer to another pointer type, so the return value of `malloc()` does not need to be type-casted explicitly in C.

C++ does not allow the compiler to perform such an implicit conversion, so the return value of `malloc()` must be type-casted explicitly in C++.

No type-cast is needed for the return value of `new` in C++, because it returns a pointer of the type that it creates, it does not return a `void*` pointer.