# return type of a function

Tags: c++

I came across this code but I couldn't understand it:

`void *operator new(unsigned int some_variable)` -> Here `new` is a function but I can't understand what `void *operator` is doing and here is the complete code:

```
int buf[3];   

void *operator new(unsigned int uiSize)
{
    return (void *)buf;
}
```

Comment: "`operator new`" is the *name* of the function (even if it is called only with `new`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry I don't follow, is it operator overloading?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus it is

Comment: More detail there: [operator_new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885849/difference-between-new-operator-and-operator-new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [**Operator Overloading**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/) that defines an implementation for the operator `new` and returns [**Void Pointer**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/void-pointer-c-cpp/)

For more information about overloading in C++, you can check this link.

[C++ Overloading](https://www.javatpoint.com/cpp-overloading)