# Why use the "new" operator?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

The code below is an example that was used to demonstrate some logic in C++

```
int *p = new int;
*p = 5;

cout << *p << endl;

delete p;
```

Comment: There is no reason to use new in the code.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: OP's phrasing is correct, this is the **`new` operator**.  Which as you say is distinct from the **deallocation function which is named `operator new()`**

Comment: This code looks like an example of how to allocate an object (in this case, an `int`) from the global store (typically the *heap*), assign it a value, print it out, and then delete the object (returning the allocated memory back to the global store).

Comment: @Eljay free store*

Comment: ***Why did we use “new” operator here? (Please explain briefly)*** I would say it's for teaching purposes but in modern code you should avoid `new` there really is not a good reason to use `new` for this code.

Comment: To dereference a pointer (for example, using `*p`) it is necessary for that pointer to point at (at least one) valid object.    Initialising `p` using `new int` is one way of achieving that.

Comment: @BenVoigt Can you please refer me to a definition for "new operator"? I can only find "operator new" and "new expression" and I assumed they meant "operator new".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You are correct. It's a [_new-expression_](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new) consisting, in part, of a keyword. There's no operator here. There is _one_ example of "new operator" in the language wording (http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#4) but that looks like an editorial mistake to me.

Comment: It looks like "new operator" [is a widely used term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885849/difference-between-new-operator-and-operator-new) but it seems to me like it is not an actual term used by the language.

Comment: @BenVoigt [`new` is not an operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.operators).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: It most certainly is an operator.  See https://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper.general#nt:operator which defines "operator".

Comment: @BenVoigt No, that's the grammar production for constructing `operator new`. I have linked you already to the standard's definition of what is and is not an operator. I concede the terminology used in that grammar production is a little misleading (as not everything under the terminal _operator_ is actually an operator), but it's still fairly clear.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: It's the grammar production for operators.  See the footnote https://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper.general#note-1 which calls them "operators", twice.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: You incorrectly linked the preprocessor operators.

Comment: @François - It's a colloquialism for the keyword in the new expression, used by the standard itself too https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.new#4.sentence-3 - if memory serves, it used to be in the normative text back in antiquity, but only the note remains now.

Comment: @Ben Those are _not_ just preprocessing operators. This is how the grammar is defined. Read the start of /1 again. I have nothing to add over what I've already said. You are, simply, mistaken. ‍♂️

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: No, those are how tokens are defined.  The standard explicitly says that not every operator is a single token, and also lists a new of them that tokenize as keywords.  That does not mean they are not operators.

Comment: I've removed my comment. Although "new operator" is not technically correct, it seems the term is well established. Edit : I'd advise the use of the technically correct "new expression" in the future.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: It IS technically correct.  `new` is an operator, along with `new[]`, `co_await`, `noexcept`, `sizeof`, and a whole host of operators that do not appear on the lexer's  operator-or-punctuator list.

Comment: Lets move this out of the comments : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64448328/is-new-in-new-int-considered-an-operator

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings • thank you for the correction.  (Alas, past the window to edit it.)

Comment: Thanks! now I am a PRO in this

Comment: Thanks! now I am a PRO in this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular example, there is no reason for dynamic allocation (which is what `new` provides).

It looks like a toy example to show how you *would* dynamically allocate, set, print, then delete an `int`.

In reality, you wouldn't do this unless you had a more complex type to create, or you *really* needed the `int` to be shared between scopes for some reason (though, even then, smart pointers are nowadays preferred).

Refer to your book for more information on dynamic allocation and when it is (and isn't) useful.

Comment: Your book will explain in more detail Naitik. If you don't have one, you're going to want to [get one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4386278).

Comment: Thanks! now I am a PRO in this

Comment: That was quick...!